# Auto Copy Web.debug.config over web.config?

Tags: .net, web-config

I know if I choose "debug" from the configuration manager and publish the site it will use the debug script. I am wondering while I am in VS though if I can somehow make it so if I choose the "debug" from the dropdown it will overright the web.config on next built so that way I can use the different modes while in VS and not just when I publish.

Comment: The behaviour is different depending on your web project. Is it a web site or web application?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC so Web application I believe.

Comment: "copy" is the wrong behavior.  Web.debug.config defines how web.config should be updated for debug deployments, those updates can involve adding, removing, or updating various parts of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very practical valid question That I faced at my work for my MVC app.

I have tried it in my project (deployed over staging / Dev builds and Prod) and it works very good.

Here is the way you can achieve it (very decent article by Scott Hansleman)

[Publishing Different Web.Config based on Environment profile](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx)